# How best to handle the covid and covid-19 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed we now have a [covid](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid) tag (3 questions) and a [covid-19](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) tag (537 questions)?

Is there any reason why we want two tags, or would it be best to merge and synonymize them?

Answer (score 3):

Of the 3 questions with the [covid](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid) tag, 1 is closed and the other 2 are referring to COVID-19.

As such, I recommend we merge them into [covid-19](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) and create a synonym for [covid](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid).

It is possible that someday we may need to have a generic [covid](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid) tag, but it appears there is no need for one now.